# Amend a git rebase

Tags: git

I did a `git rebase master` which involved some manual merging in three files.  In one of them, I missed a trailing newline, resulting in the following at the end of the file:

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
=======

>>>>>>> ... commit message
```

which naturally results in a PHP error.  I can fix the file easily enough, but I don't want to add an erroneous "fix sloppy rebase" commit.

How can I amend this change to the rebase?  Or, repeat the rebase so I can catch it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This question basically boils down to "how do I modify a commit that's not the most recent?". Assuming that you haven't pushed the commit anywhere, and further assuming that history is linear from that commit onwards, it's pretty easy.

1. Make the change you want to apply to your earlier commit.
2. Figure out what the earlier commit you want to modify is. For the sake of these instructions we'll call it `$SHA` but you can use any means you want to identify this commit.
3. Run `git commit --fixup $SHA`.
4. Run `git rebase -i --autosquash $SHA^`

This will give you an editor with a list of commits. The first commit should be `$SHA`, the second should be your edit, and following that should be the rest of the commits up to `HEAD`. Save and close this editor. Git will now do an interactive rebase, applying your change to the commit you wanted to modify.

---

There's an alternative solution you can use, which is a bit more manual, but works without the interactive rebase. Basically, you can checkout the commit you want to modify directly (producing a detached head), make your change, run `git commit --amend`, and then rebase the branch back on top of your new amended commit. You may actually prefer this style since it's a bit more explicit about what you're doing, but the benefit of the interactive rebase version is you can do a lot more things with an interactive rebase. For example, you can reorder commits, squash multiple commits together, delete commits, reword commits, and more. You can also use the `--fixup` and `--squash` flags to `git commit` to record these actions that you wish to perform without actually doing the rebase immediately, and then you can go back and do one big interactive rebase when you're done.

Comment: Would the commit I want to modify be the first commit of the branch?  The errant lines show in a diff between that commit and the latest from master, just rebased in.

Comment: please explain "then rebase the branch back on top of your new amended commit".  I am unclear about whether I am supposed to run `git rebase [branch]` while in detached head, or `git rebase [commit]` after.

Comment: @Umbrella: Whatever commit introduces the lines you want to modify is the one you want to target. It sounds like it probably is the first commit from your branch. As for the explanation, when you're on your detached head, after amending the commit, you can use `git rebase HEAD [branch]` (which checks out the branch and rebases it on top of what was `HEAD`, i.e. your amended commit).

Comment: Rebasing the commit as described in your last comment worked for me.  Thank you.

Comment: I am just experimenting with git stuff and find this very cool. Thank you for your contribution.

Answer (score 1):

You could make the change and then `git commit --amend`.

Comment: Doing this results in the removal of those lines showing up in the last commit.  This is different than correcting the rebase.

Comment: Incidentally, I now also need to know how to clean that up.

Comment: I see. Was the rest of the rebase successful? If so, you should be able to `git reset --hard [ref of the commit just before the bad merge]` and then rebase again. If you don't mind my asking, what's the big deal about a mildly sloppy commit?

Comment: Sorry for the schadenfreude, but your second comment made me LOL.

Comment: @Umbrella: You can use the reflog to undo your amend. If the `git commit --amend` was the very last command you executed (at least, the last command that modified anything), then you can use `git reset --hard HEAD@{1}` to undo it (or `--soft` to leave your change intact in the index).

Comment: There is no commit representing the rebase, so how would I reset to the commit just before it?  That would be the current HEAD.  Also, my second comment amused me as I wrote it.

Comment: @Brandan, oh, and, the big deal is, if I just throw in the sloppy commit, I won't learn.

Comment: @KevinBallard, I executed other commands, such as trying Brandan's suggestion.  How would I then use reflog?

Comment: If you're still in the middle of the rebase, you can `git rebase --abort` to completely start over. Otherwise, I'm deferring to @KevinBallard.

Comment: @Umbrella: I didn't realize you were in the middle of a rebase when you were trying to apply Brandan's suggestion. As Brandan says, `git rebase --abort` should cancel the rebase. Otherwise, you can use `git log -g [branch]` to show the reflog for your branch, and you can figure out if any of those commits represent what your branch was before you tried making any changes. If you find a commit that looks good, you can then `git reset --hard $commit`.

Comment: I was not in the middle of the rebase.  That would have been easy to get out of ;)